# Outlook ignoring HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE entry for add-in on startup

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, registrykey

I have a C# Add-In for Outlook 2013 64 bit on Win10 64 bit developed using VS 2017 and .Net 4.6.

I have the required registry entries under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\LegalFirst.OutlookToMatter
```

but the Add-In does not get loaded.

If I put the identical registry entries under HKCU the add-in loads just fine.

I want this add-in to be for all users.

The add-in was installed using VS and Windows Installer and it correctly created the HKLM entries.  Not sure if its relevant but it did not have a trusted installer certificate.  Happy to provide any additional info.

Can anyone offer some suggestions please.

Comment: Have you looked into the Windows Event log to see if Outlook has problems loading your addin? Have you tried to use ProcMan to see if it tries to access your addin? Are you sure you did not create the registry entries in the Wow6432Node hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!  Even though it is installed under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15" it is a 32 bit process and so is not looking at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office at all but only HKLM\WOW6432Node\Software\Microsoft\Office.

Thanks to @dmitry-streblechenko for suggesting Procmon which lead me to procexp which showed that my oulook.exe was actually a 32 bit process.

Change my installer to x86 and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

An installer for 64-bit Windows requires two registry paths because it's possible for users to run 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office on a computer that runs 64-bit Windows.

Read more about these configurations in the [To specify whether you want to support per-user or per-computer installations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019#to-specify-whether-you-want-to-support-per-user-or-per-computer-installations) section.

Finally, you may find the [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) article helpful.